# Updating stock quantity in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have `pallet_quantity` column in my `supplier` table, and when a customer places an order, in the `orderdetails` table they have already meant the pallet quantity that they want.

I'm trying to update my pallet quantity in `supplierpalletquantity` with a trigger when I take order in the `orderdetails` table. That's why I tried to build something like this but I get errors.

```
CREATE TRIGGER QuantityUpdate
ON OrderDetails 
FOR UPDATE
NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Supplier
    SET Supplier.SuppPalletQuantity = (Supplier.SuppPalletQuantity - OrderDetails.Pallet_Quantity) 
END
```

How can I solve this issue? Please help me. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Why is this done in an UPDATE trigger and not an INSERT trigger? Suggest you focus on the INSERT logic first since it will be simpler. Triggers generally use the virtual INSERTED and DELETED table to know which rows have been affected. Your code, as posted, is simply syntactically invalid - a fact that you neglect to mention. If you don't have a good grasp of basic SQL, writing a trigger will be difficult (to put it kindly).

Comment: Your table schema would help immensely

Comment: _That's why I tried to build something like this but I get errors._ Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70999000/edit) your question to include the full and complete error message - as text, not screen shot(s).